# Android - internal data save getFilesDir()?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am downloading from web and APK update file with this code:

```
        URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
        HttpURLConnection connection2 = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection2.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection2.setDoOutput(true);
        connection2.connect();
        int lenghtOfFile = connection2.getContentLength();

        String PATH = ctx.getFilesDir()+"/";
        File apkdir=new File (PATH);
        apkdir.mkdirs();
        File newInstall=new File(apkdir, "app.apk");

        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(newInstall);

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

        long total = 0;

        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            publishProgress((int)(total*100/lenghtOfFile));
            prog=(int)(total*100/lenghtOfFile);
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {}

    return null;
```

and for opening file I use this:

```
    Intent install=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    install.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(ctx.getFilesDir()+"/app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
```

And here comes the problem - I am ablte to store downloaded app into Context.getFilesDir(), but when I prompt installation pricess, logcat says "unable to read androidmanifest.xml. Where do you see the problem? I need to download into internal, not accesible memory by user, because of security reasons.

Comment: Is the file in it's entirety being downloaded?

Comment: Yea, files is completely beeing downloaded

Answer (score 3):

> I need to download into internal, not accesible memory by user, because of security reasons.

This is complete nonsense. A user will still be able to get at your downloaded file, particularly if you install it.

Your problem is that the installer cannot read the file. Either store it in external storage, or you will need to use `openFileOutput()` with `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` instead of `new FileOutputStream` to get your `OutputStream`.

Comment: I didn't actually mean Internal memory, I meant folder app/data, which is unable to open by the user. But I will try, thx

Comment: @Hmyzak: "I meant folder app/data, which is unable to open by the user" -- users can access that if they root their phones. And, since you have to allow the OS to read the file, users will be able to read it as well.

Comment: OK, it is ment by casual user, which doesn't want to break into the phone. Otherwise, nothing in Android is in secret

Comment: @CommonsWare - this question is still unanswered. There is problem with permission to get data from getFilesDir();

Comment: @Hmyzak: Then put it on external storage. Again, you are gaining precisely zero security by putting it on internal storage, as once your application is installed, anyone can get the APK even without root. You might also consider using proper code for assembling your `Uri` -- never create paths via concatenation (use the proper `File` constructor instead).

Comment: @CommonsWare - user of my app will be general users, not thoose who root their phones. Again I am asking on specific problem and I am not given advice for only one thing I want to know, but many others. I am not willing to put it on external storage because of security reasons

Comment: @Hmyzak: If `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` does not work for you (though I would have expected it should), and you are unwilling to use external storage, then you will simply have to not write this application, or at least not deploy this nested APK this way.

Comment: @CommonsWare you're quite correct in your advice to the OP about the "security" reasons for doing this. However there are other valid reasons for wanting to do this such as supporting devices which don't have a sdcard mounted at time of fetching the update apk (as in my case). And I can confirm that using `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` does work, though you end up having to use an ugly workaround to get the path of the file that you write using the `openFileOutput()` API.